# Need help in replacing space with hyphen in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I tried so many options available on this website but couldn't fix my problem. 
My Code:

```
<?php       
$district = $_GET['district'];
$state = $_GET['state'];        
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','codeslib_service','service','codeslib_vdr123');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}    

// the query, limit the number of results to 5
$sql="SELECT * FROM pincodes WHERE districtName='$district' AND stateName='$state'";    
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);      
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();    
$district = $row['districtName'];   
$office = $row['officeName'];       
$state = $row['stateName'];
$pincode = $row['pinCode'];
?>
```

.htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ district.php?state=$1&district=$2 [L]`

Now, the above code is generating URL like `domainname.com/pincode/Delhi/Andhra Pradesh`

while I don't want to have space in the URL, but would like to replace space with hyphen (-). 
Tried so many things but no gain, Please help me with this.

Thanks,

Vikas

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this code before any other rule in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?/(.*)\ (.*)$ /$1-$2   [L,R=301]
```

**This will replace space from URL to  hyphen(-)**

Comment: I don't understand ?tag here. Did you mean ?district or ?state here? Or could you provide me this rule adding the exact rule after picking appropriate tags from my code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried str_replace ?

like str_replace(" ", "-", $url);

Comment: Yes pali, I did but no gain. This was helpful in anchor tags but not in the $_GET thing

Answer (score 0):

```
# keep replacing space to hyphen until there is no space use internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)[\s%20]+(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=NOSPACE:1]

# when there is no space make an external redirection
RewriteCond %{ENV:NOSPACE} =1
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

This will replace all space characters (`\s` or `%20`) to hyphen `-`

So a URI of `/tag/bob%20hope%20is%20funny` will become `/tag/bob-hope-is-funny` with 301

Comment: Shailesh I've already tried it but no benefit, problem persisted continuously.

Answer (score 0):

To replace all spaces by hyphens you can use this rule at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect when only one space is left    
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*)$" /$1-$2 [L,R=302]

# otherwise rewrite by replacing each space by -
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*\s+.*)$" $1-$2 [L]
```

Comment: It works fine on my local apache. Make sure these are first rules and greet to enable rewrite log and post it on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally cracked it, I have used str_replace in the following way:

str_replace("-", " ", $url);

While in google and on the forums, I noticed that first value was space then hyphen, I've to reverse it to use hyphen based urls :)